# SQL Server - Convert Days as Column, Hour as row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm looking for a way to convert rows to display datetime data's day as column and hour as first row in one month.
This is my example data in a month:

```
Time                   | Value
--------------------------------
2016-10-01 00:00:00    | 23
2016-10-01 00:30:00    | 35
.....                  | .....
2016-10-31 23:30:00    | 52
```

The result i want is

```
Time          |   1   | .... |   31   |  <-- Day 1 - 31
---------------------------------------
00:00:00      |  23   | .... |  ....  |
00:30:00      |  35   | .... |  ....  |
...           | ....  | .... |  ....  |
23:30:00      | ....  | .... |   52   |
```

How can i build the result?

Comment: What should happen when there is more than one `Value` for same `Time` ?

Comment: Also how do you plan to show data from multiple months ?

Comment: @Prdp The data has no same value for same time

Comment: @M.Ali the month is an input to generate the result i want, for example, the above result is the result i want to generate for october

Comment: Do it the other way.  Make the columns times and the hours rows.  Almost every day has exactly 24 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Conditional Aggregate` to do this

```
select cast([Time] as time),
       Max(case when DAY([Time]) = 1 then Value end) As [1]
       Max(case when DAY([Time]) = 2 then Value end) As [2]
       Max(case when DAY([Time]) = 3 then Value end) As [3]
       .....
       Max(case when DAY([Time]) = 31 then Value end) As [31]
From yourtable
Where Month([Time]) = 10 -- pass the required month  
Group by cast([Time] as time)
```

Comment: I thinking of a more sleek solution where if the month is February, dates are shown only to 28 or 29 if the year is linear , but I guess to keep things simple this should work too :)

Comment: Yes, this work as i want. One more question, can the number of day column generated based on the number of days of the month entered?

Comment: @KukuhHeruIrawan - you need to use dynamic query for it